# Tunneling all connections of an application through a proxy with Hooking wsocks32.dll

Tags: c++, api, hook

I have find this project from internet and i want to developing it.

Project has two parts.

1. An Injector app.

2. A dll for injecting to app (chrome.exe or any app.)
as Tunneling all connections of an application through a proxy.

1. Dll injector program.  Works  fine!

2. Injector app runs "chrome.exe" and injecting my DLL to chrome. Works  fine!

3. My dll must replace "wsocks32.dll" functions to my dll functions in the chrome.exe..Fail!

4. Opened web sites from Chrome.exe, must work through proxy...Fail!

Problem: 

This funtion "ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod" is replacing functions of an application. 
But wsock32.dll functions cant be replacing. 
I cant hook to wsock32.dll!

```
 ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod("wsock32.dll",(PROC)OriginalConnect,(PROC)MyConnect,hModCaller);**
```

---

But, Kernel.dll's functions replacing process is success, works fine.

```
ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod( "KERNEL32.dll",(PROC)OriginalLoadLibraryW,(PROC)MyLoadLibraryW,hModCaller );
```

Anyone help me for what cause?
My operation system is Win7.

My Function:

```
int ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod( PCSTR pszCalleeModName,PROC pfnCurrent, PROC pfnNew, HMODULE hModCaller )
{
ULONG ulSize;
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImportDesc;
pImportDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)
ImageDirectoryEntryToData( hModCaller, TRUE,
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT, &ulSize );
if (pImportDesc == NULL)
    return 2;  
for(; pImportDesc->Name; pImportDesc++)
{
    PSTR pszModName;
    pszModName = (PSTR)((PBYTE)hModCaller + pImportDesc->Name );
    if ( lstrcmpiA( pszModName, pszCalleeModName ) == 0 ) break;
}

if ( pImportDesc->Name == 0 ) 
    return 1;  

PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA pThunk;
pThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((PBYTE)hModCaller + pImportDesc->FirstThunk );

for (; pThunk->u1.Function; pThunk++)
{
    PROC* ppfn = (PROC*)&pThunk->u1.Function;
    if (*ppfn == pfnCurrent)
    {
        DWORD dwDummy;
        VirtualProtect( ppfn, sizeof(PROC), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwDummy );

        WriteProcessMemory( hCurrentProcess, ppfn, &pfnNew, sizeof(PROC),NULL);
        return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some debugging results to your question. Where does the code not do what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod("wsock32.dll",(PROC)OriginalConnect,(PROC)MyConnect,hModCaller);
```

to

```
ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod("WS2_32.dll",(PROC)OriginalConnect,(PROC)MyConnect,hModCaller);
```